# Down carat doesn't render within Office UI Fabric React's drop down component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu, office-ui-fabric

My code currently doesn't render the down facing carat.

Here's the code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dropdown";
import * as styles from "./dropdownMenu.scss";
import { ResponsiveMode } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/utilities/decorators/withResponsiveMode";

export class DropDownMenu extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.size}>
        <Dropdown
          placeHolder="Select an option"
          id="timeFilterMenu"
          ariaLabel="Select a time filter for the analytics"
          defaultSelectedKey="B"
          options={[
            { key: "A", text: "Last 7 days" },
            { key: "B", text: "Last 28 days" }
          ]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's what it renders:
[no chevron rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R00ai.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to initialize the icons using

```
import { initializeIcons } from '@uifabric/icons';
initializeIcons();
```

You only need to do that once in your app, so maybe place it in your entrypoint (e.g. App.js)